# Rails/ActiveRecord/SQLite3: Can't save records in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, activerecord

I have a Rails app using sqlite3. Anytime I want to save anything in test environment I'm getting the following error:

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
    SQLite3::SQLException: near "SAVEPOINT": syntax error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

In development, everything works fine. I'm using Rails 3.2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade your OS default version of Sqlite

http://shynnergy.com/2012/07/savepoint-exception-with-rails-3-1-on-jenkins/

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Although I used "option 1" in the Stackoverflow post your block post references to, the bundler option did not work for me.